# what is the meaning of 0(zero) in the find method of simple HTML DOM parser library?

Tags: php, html, dom

I am studying a simple DOM parser. I am unable to understand the meaning of 0

```
$single = $html->find('#foo', 0);
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find will return an array, `0` represent the index of that array, so basically you are grabbing the first element of the result of `find()`.

`$single = $html->find('#foo', 0);`

Comment: <html><body><p>Hello World!</p><p>Were here</p></body></html>
I want to print second p element and my code is like this. I know if if echo $element[1] it print second p tag element but I want to know if I put 1 in find() method why it show the error.
                $element = $html->find("p",1);
              echo $element[0];
(erro::Cannot use object of type simple_html_dom_node as array in)